# Laravel pass collection to component

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a view which has a component for showing house properties information.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($matchs as $match)
        @component('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.matchbox')
        @endcomponent
    @endforeach
</div>
```

In my Controller i'm returning a collection and each "matchbox" is created OK depending on the total elements of the collection.

```
class OfferdemandsmatchsController extends Controller
{
    public function index ($id) {
        $matchs = DB::table('offerdemandsmatchs')
                ->join('properties', 'offerdemandsmatchs.prop_id', '=', 'properties.prop_id')
                ->where('offerdemandsmatchs.offerdemand_id', '=', $id)
                ->select('properties.*', 'offerdemandsmatchs.created_at as matchcreated_at', 'offerdemandsmatchs.created_at as matchupdated_at',
                'offerdemandsmatchs.like', 'offerdemandsmatchs.id as matchid')
                ->get();
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.index', compact('matchs'));

    }
}
```

The problem i'm facing is that I want to pass variable $match to each box, it looks like components only accept an array and not a collection.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($matchs as $match)
        @component('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.matchbox', $match)
        @endcomponent
    @endforeach
</div>
```

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\View\Factory::startComponent() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Desarrollo\laragon\www\kw-plataforma\storage\framework\views\60fac8943d076d952347a84172f358cd1ee65f54.php on line 39 (
```

How can I pass the data to the component box?

Regards

Comment: Use the collection's `toArray()` method?

Comment: Thanks @miken32, I tried your suggestion but it's also failing:
          
`Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\View\Factory::startComponent() must be of the type array, object given`

Comment: Have you tried `['match' => $match]` instead of just `$match`? Should be an array because you can add multiple data to the component. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz
I was my fault not passing the array correctly! Thanks!

Comment: @kerbholz maybe post that as an answer so the question can be marked as solved correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters for a component need to be an array of key => value pairs.

Replace your single parameter `$match` with an array of `['match' => $match]`. (If you need more parameters in your component you can add them to the array)

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($matchs as $match)
        @component('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.matchbox', ['match' => $match])
        @endcomponent
    @endforeach
</div>
```